# Get frame from SurfaceTexture (Android)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-service

I'm using a `SurfaceTexture` to run the camera of a device in the background and get frames from it. I see that that `onFrameAvailable` callback don't bring a frame, but a `SurfaceTexture` instead. I want to get the frame or an image representation of it, but I'm not sure how to do that. When I searched I found that I need to use GraphicBuffer, but it seems too complicated and it's not clear to me how to use it.

I've also looked at solutions here:

[Texture Image processing on the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423663/texture-image-processing-on-the-gpu)

[Android SDK: Get raw preview camera image without displaying it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775942/android-sdk-get-raw-preview-camera-image-without-displaying-it)

But it's not clear how to do it in the code. Here is my code:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service  {

    private Camera camera = null;
    private int  NOTIFICATION_ID= 1;
    private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture= new SurfaceTexture (10);
    Intent intializerIntent;





    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BackgroundService getService() {
            // Return this instance of this service so clients can call public methods
            return BackgroundService.this;
        }
    }//end inner class that returns an instance of the service.

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        intializerIntent = intent;
        return mBinder;
    }//end onBind.


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate is called");
        // Start foreground service to avoid unexpected kill

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, buildNotification());

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                camera = Camera.open(1);

                mSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(new SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "frame captured from texture");


                        if (camera!=null) {
                            //camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(null);
                            //camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                            //camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(null);

                            //if the following two lines are not called, many frames will be droped. 
                            camera.stopPreview();
                            camera.startPreview();
                        }


                    }
                });
                //now try to set the preview texture of the camera which is actually the  surfaceTexture that has just been created.

                try {
                    camera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error in setting the camera surface texture");
                }



                camera.startPreview();
            }


        };
        thread.start();

    }

    private Notification buildNotification () {

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true); //this notification should be ongoing

        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(getString (R.string.notification_text_and_ticker))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.vecsat_logo)
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.notification_text_and_ticker));
        return(notificationBuilder.build());

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed method");

        camera.stopPreview();
        //camera.lock();

        camera.release();
        mSurfaceTexture.detachFromGLContext();
        mSurfaceTexture.release();
        stopService(intializerIntent) ;
        //windowManager.removeView(surfaceView);

    }
}
```

How can I get the frames and process them whether that's on GPU or CPU? If there is a way to do that on GPU, then get the results from there, that would be great as it seems more efficient.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

SurfaceTexture takes whatever is sent to the Surface and wrangles it into an OpenGL ES "external" texture.  If you want access to those pixels from software, you will need to render the texture to a framebuffer, then read the pixels out with `glReadPixels()`.  One example of this is the bigflake [ExtractMpegFramesTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest), which converts frames of decoded video to PNG.

Better performance can be achieved by doing all processing on the GPU (see e.g. [this demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg)), but that's not always feasible.

Comment: thank you. I think this code records the video, I'm not recording it in my case. I need to read it more carefully. Please give me some time I will try to understand it and get back to you if I have a question. Thanks.

Comment: the code seems to save the video first then tries to use MediaCodec, but I couldn't understand must of it. Can you please help me? How can I use this technique in a service as in my case? Or, what other alternatives can I do on the GPU? Thank you.